# Расширения для хрома

Tags: google-chrome, html, css, javascript

В правом верхнем углу как обычно есть иконка расширения. Пользователь нажимает на нее, появляется форма ввода данных.

Как передать текст, который он ввел, другой программе на компьютере? Такой себе месседжер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может отправить текст через POST на сервер, а месседжер и так принимает все сообщения с сервера...
А напрямую скорее всего нельзя. Хром запретит.

Comment: @fremail и я так думаю.